# Query a online database

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, xcode, ftp

I know very little about databases. Is it possible to make a query to a sql server with a URL? if yes,  can you provide a sample explanation.
Also another question, what is the best way to handle this situation in code?

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to access a SQL server directly from your client code. It is too easy for a hacker to change the strings of your application, which could potentially have them drop your entire DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to query a database via URL. But you can build one on your own.

On your server, receive the query via URL and run the query and return the output of the query to the user.

But this is highly discouraged, as anyone can access your database, unless you add security measures, by asking for username/password in the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

ya you can do so by passing thee sql query as get value of the link
eg. http://www.site.com/?query=Select * from tbl
n then use that query inside of the page 
by just connecting db n executing it.. 
you will get your ans as json object
thats it

Comment: Yeah... bullet proof... Reminds me of my friend...Little Johnny Tables